# How to create a sci fi gun charging up sound effect

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound, foley

I'm trying to create a clunky sci fi gun that charges up before blasting someone to bits. I'm finding it difficult on how to create a charging sound effect! Any tips or tricks would be awesome!

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when I think of a "charging" sound, I instantly think of something *increasing*. Level, pitch, both maybe.

I would have a sustained sound, slowly increasing in pitch, maybe an exponentially increasing rise speed, with some distortion to start off, which attenuates as the charge reaches it's limit. I would have another sound increasing in level as the pitch rises, maybe an octave or two above the base sound. I would also add some ring modulation to add some interesting movement to the sound as it increases. As you say a "clunky" gun, I'd add some effects to make the charge sound slightly worn, like the gun needs a service!

I hope this was the type of thing you were looking for. Good Luck!